# Generate columns of top ranked values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `topic_data` that contains the output of an LDA topic model:

```
topic_data.head(15)

    topic                      word     score
0       0                Automobile  0.063986
1       0                   Vehicle  0.017457
2       0                Horsepower  0.015675
3       0                    Engine  0.014857
4       0                   Bicycle  0.013919
5       1                     Sport  0.032938
6       1      Association_football  0.025324
7       1                Basketball  0.020949
8       1                  Baseball  0.016935
9       1  National_Football_League  0.016597
10      2                     Japan  0.051454
11      2                      Beer  0.032839
12      2                   Alcohol  0.027909
13      2                     Drink  0.019494
14      2                     Vodka  0.017908
```

This shows the top 5 terms for each topic, and the score (weight) for each. What I'm trying to do is reformat so that the index is the rank of the term, the columns are the topic IDs, and the values are formatted strings generated from the `word` and `score` columns (something along the lines of `"%s (%.02f)" % (word,score)`). That means the new dataframe should look something like this:

```
Topic  0                1                            ...
Rank
  0  Automobile (0.06)  Sport (0.03)                 ...
  1  Vehicle (0.017)    Association_football (0.03)  ...
 ... ...                ...                          ...
```

What's the right way of going about this? I assume it involves a combination of index-setting, unstacking, and ranking, but I'm not sure of the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this, note that `Rank` has to be generated first:

```
In [140]:
df['Rank']    = (-1*df).groupby('topic').score.transform(np.argsort)
df['New_str'] = df.word + df.score.apply(' ({0:.2f})'.format)
df2           = df.sort(['Rank', 'score'])[['New_str', 'topic','Rank']]
print df2.pivot(index='Rank', values='New_str', columns='topic')

topic                  0                                1               2
Rank                                                                     
0      Automobile (0.06)                     Sport (0.03)    Japan (0.05)
1         Vehicle (0.02)      Association_football (0.03)     Beer (0.03)
2      Horsepower (0.02)                Basketball (0.02)  Alcohol (0.03)
3          Engine (0.01)                  Baseball (0.02)    Drink (0.02)
4         Bicycle (0.01)  National_Football_League (0.02)    Vodka (0.02)
```